# break between php return and html

Tags: html, css

I cannot understand why there is a break between "Hello 1" and "Logout". Can anybody see why?

[image]

```
<h4 class="hello">Hello, <em><?php echo $_SESSION['username'];?>!</em></h4>
            <a href="logout.php" style="font-size:18px">Logout?</a>
            <a href="test.php">test</a>
        <div id="container">
            <div class="topbar">
                <p id="headline">Test</p>
                <p id="headline_1">Page</p>

            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Because your `Hello` is inside the `<h4>` tag,. and the `Logout` is outside it.

Comment: your h4 tag creates default margin and padding between the content..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Headings, including `h4` elements, are `display: block` by default so they generate line breaks before and after themselves.

You can alter that by:

- Not using a heading element (the text doesn't look like it is a sub-sub-sub heading so this is probably the best approach).
- Modifying the `display`
- Floating elements
- Using Flexbox
- Using CSS grids

Answer (score 0):

Reason is described by some people as above. One solution can be like this:

```
<div>
    <span class="hello">
      Hello, <em><?php echo $_SESSION['username'];?>!</em>
    </span>
    <a href="logout.php" style="font-size:18px">Logout?</a>
</div>
```